# Oracle: Bulk collect into "table of number" gives "numeric or value error"

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I've come across an example of doing this on the net which also fails on my DB (10g) but here's my version.

```
...
TYPE prog_rec_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

prog_rec_list prog_rec_type;

begin

...

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT PROGRESS_RECID FROM ' || v_table_name || v_where BULK COLLECT INTO prog_rec_list;


--ERROR FOUND IN THIS SECTION
FOR i IN prog_rec_list.FIRST..prog_rec_list.LAST
LOOP


--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FOR LOOP: ' || i);

null;

END LOOP;

...
END;
```

Much appreciate the help.

Comment: Perhaps check that some rows were found? e.g. `IF prog_rec_list.COUNT > 0 THEN FOR i in ...`

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, school boy error there. I'd assumed it was some setting in 10G as another online example failed as well. live and learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result set is empty. So you need to check that you got some results from that SELECT PROGRESS_RECID FROM ' || v_table_name || v_where

Comment: Excactly. FOR i in NULL..NULL throws a "numeric or value error".

Answer (score 1):

you may try this,

```
FOR i IN 1 .. prog_rec_list.COUNT LOOP
..
END LOOP
```